# Connecting my PC to my router kills the internet connection (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet

I was browsing the internet yesterday and out of nowhere my internet connection died. All the lights in my router (Arris TG862) went dark except for the power light. I disconnected all ethernet cables from the router and turned it off and on again. It started working again. The problem is that as soon as I plug the ethernet cable coming from my desktop PC into the router it stops working. I have a laptop (Ubuntu) and another device connected to the router and it's all working fine, but as soon as I plug the PC in it kills everything.

I tried using different cables. I tried reinstalling the network adapter's (Onboard Realtek) driver. I tried resetting the router. I did some tests with a diagnostic utility for the network adapter and it passed all tests.

One thing that I noticed is that one time when I plugged everything in the router (PC, laptop, etc), something poped up in the Windows PC about an IP conflict. Everything is DHCP, no static IPs.

Any help will be appreciated.

edit: One more thing, my windows PC also doesn't detect the wireless connection coming from the router

Comment: An IP conflict definitely makes sense, I think. The fact that everything is DHCP is puzzling however. Most routers will let you view a list of connected devices and their associated IP and MAC addresses. Perhaps a good starting point is to statically assign this problem computer to an IP that you know for a fact is free based on this list, and then try connecting it. The fact that this happened out of nowhere also kind of suggests faulty NIC hardware which is not unheard of. If you have the equipment, you might try a loopback test on the NIC in question.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure of some sort. If the PC is forcing the router to power off, it may be a short in the PC's network card. Have you run any diagnostics? Try a different network card in the PC. IF that resolves it, the original one is bad.

Comment: NIC's are cheap so there's that, do you have more than one network adapter in your motherboard now?  I know a lot come with 2 these days, could try the other one.  Also, try updating your drivers from within device manager (right click -> "Update Driver Software").  I recently updated my realtek driver that way and it fixed some problems I was having.

Comment: The ISP guy came an replaced the router and now it's working. The NIC is fine, apparently.